# Why the wrapping div don't have a required classname appended in cakephp?

Tags: class, validation, cakephp, required, formhelper

The cakebook says "The wrapping `div` will have a required classname appended if the validation rules for the Model’s field do not specify `allowEmpty => true`. ", and we can also use `notEmpty` to add the required classname.

```
class Admin extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Admin';

    public $validate = array(
        'symbol' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    )
}
```

But it just comes to `<div class="input text">` likes this:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BLVf-RwCMAAAV5A.jpg

```
<div class="input text">
  <label for="AdminSymbol">symbol</label>
  <input name="data[Admin][symbol]" type="text" id="AdminSymbol">
</div>
```

Why there's no `required` in the `div class` ?

Well,I find the problem,my friend use `AdminModel`.php as the file name which should be `Admin.php`.My friend is a fool!!!_(:3」∠)_累感不爱

Then,how to close the question?

Comment: does the validation itself work? does it invalidate if nothing is posted in this field? also, why didnt you mention your cakephp version?

Comment: TAT.It seems that the validation does not work.What should I do?My cakephp is 2.3.5.

Comment: a) dropt that $name stuff. b) use a more verbose validate array as described in the docs. c) post your controller code as this is usually the reason why it breaks if the model validation setup is in order.

Comment: Well,I find the problem,my friend use `AdminModel.php` as the file name which should be `Admin.php`.My friend is a fool!!!_(:3」∠)_累感不爱

Comment: "Then,how to close the question?": you close the question either deleting it completely, or answer your own question with the solution and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way could help you

To modify the wrapping element type and its class, use the following format:

```
$this->Form->input('Model.field', array(
    'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'bzzz'))
));
```

Comment: before that first check is your validation rules correctly working or not ?

Comment: my friend use AdminModel.php as the file name which should be Admin.php.My friend is a fool!!!_(:3」∠)_累感不爱